# "FOR UPDATE" in an "EXISTS SELECT" statement

Tags: select, locking, transaction, mysql-5.7, exists

Is there any potential problem in using (in a transaction)

```
SELECT EXISTS( SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id=36 FOR UPDATE )
```

i.e. having `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` within an `EXISTS`?

MySQL does certainly some optimizations for `EXISTS` since it doesn't have to actually retrieve the data, and, just in case, was wondering if the row where id=36 will be locked anyway, as expected?